# how to read the scientific value from the CSV or Excel file using java?

Tags: java

Example,

In a CSV or Excel file I'm storing one integer value '1544887451541840' but it is adding as scientific value '1.54489E+15' in that file, if we are reading that cell value in java code it is reading as '1.54489E+15'.but I want that value as '1544887451541840'.

Comment: Reading it in Java code how?

Comment: You can never read `1.54489E+15` as `1544887451541840`. There simply isn't enough precision left in your input value.

Comment: Then don't store it as a float type.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem you are facing is more linked to the printing of the value then of the value itself. Note that any calculation involving the number with the scientific notation will still be correctly computed by Java.

To fix the printing issue, be sure that the value read from the Excel file is interpreted as a `BigInteger`, instead of a standard `int` value.
Then, when you print out the variable, be sure to utilize the `toPlainString()` method.

For instance:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.54489745154184E+15");
    String str = bd.toPlainString();
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```

Will output `1544887451541840`.